# How to get rid of blue box surrounding text pressed using detail tag (in html)

Tags: html, wordpress

On Wordpress, when I click the text that drops down a list (done using the detail tag), a blue rectangular box forms around the text. Is there any way, using only html, to prevent this from happening? (I don't have the availability of CSS on my Wordpress.com blog.) Thanks

[image]

Comment: use outline:0px for your dropdown box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Wordpress allows inline css by default. So, depending on your settings, the following might work:

```
<details>
    <summary style="outline:none";>Alabama</summary>
    <p>Domino's</p>
    <p>Donatos</p>
</details>
```

http://clarkwp.wordpress.com/2013/11/07/inline-css-styling-in-wordpress/

Comment: It worked once, but then I saved the changes to the post and it removed all of the code where I inserted "style="outline:none";." Not sure why.

Comment: After having the code deleted a few times, if you just keep reentering it, it eventually stays. Tedious, but it works.